# How to install VMware Horizon Client 4.5.0 on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: package-management

(I'm a Linux newbie.  Just installed Ubuntu 17.04)

I tried following the directions posted by a user for 16.04 at [How to install VMware Horizon Client 4.5.0 on Ubuntu 16.04LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/931691/how-to-install-vmware-horizon-client-4-5-0-on-ubuntu-16-04lts)

When I run the command:

```
sudo apt-get install libgstreamer0.10-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev
```

I get the responses:

```
Unable to locate package...
```

for both packages.

Without these packages, Horizon client install says that it fails "Multimedia redirection".

How can I get these packages installed on 17.04?

Answer (score 2):

There's a newer version in 17.04. Try pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> twice to see available options ;)

```
sudo apt-get install libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev
sudo apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-dev
sudo apt-get install v4l-utils
```